# Serial-port communication

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I'm developing a software that lets you manage the serial-port communication in an easier way, through a C++ wrapper class. But I've run into some doubts;
for example, I wanna show a simple message on the other screen:

1)There is the need of a "listening server" (and then set it up)? Or it gets written directly, like this example:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  int fd = open("/dev/tty2", O_RDWR);
  write(fd, "Hello World", sizeof("Hello World"));
  return 0;
}
```

(just to show the behavior)
2) I run the program on the sender computer. On the second one, what I've to do?
The two machines run Linux both.
Please give me as much information as you can, I've never treated this (old) communication style.

Edit: **In every program I've found so far, both the read and write are in the same program. I'd know why.**

Comment: I believe you should show you entire code, probably by publishing your software under some [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-software) license. And [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)-s are really complex and arcane; you'll benefit a lot from code review!

Comment: Have you looked at [LibSerial](http://libserial.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Just for reference: [QextSerialPort](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) and [Boost](http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html)

Comment: I have to make my own class and **not** using some made by somebody else. Please read the topic.

Comment: The program usually contains both the read and write functionality because serial communications are typically bi-directional.

Comment: Do you mean it works like a TCP client-server communication? I don't think there's an handshake, though; but just focus on the example.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want.  What do you mean, second computer?  The thing at the other end of the serial cable?  Usually you won't use serial to connect two computers, because it's so much slower than Ethernet and other network technologies.  Serial is generally used to attach peripherals where the processor isn't fast enough for Ethernet, etc.  Explain what your whole wiring setup looks like.  If it has to work with different serial devices, pick one as an example, and say (but could instead be *whatever*).

Comment: I asked: " I wanna **show** a **simple message** on the **other screen**". Then you should have figured out what I wanted to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally tested, yes, you've to set a listener and a writer program. Kind of client-server, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Often sending and receiving are implemented in one program. So you have the same program on both machines even if you send always from the same machine and receive on the other.
If you want to communicate both ways you need sending and receiving in the same application. But then you need a synchronization mechanism.